# How to get a string on two lines in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

I have a very long SQLite statement that I need to split on multiple lines. However, when I try to simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> WebStorm creates a new string and concatenates it. I don't really want this, however.

Is there a way to stop WebStorm from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiline string literals are not allowed in JavaScript, the IDE just tries to keep your code valid.

If you like your string literal to occupy several lines, I'd suggest changing your string literals to [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). In IDE, you can easily transform a simple string into template string using the **Replace with template string** intention:

[image]